# brew how install cmake libaio-devel libffi-devel glib2 glib2-devel

Tags: linux, homebrew

1. yum | apt-get  install cmake libaio-devel libffi-devel glib2 glib2-devel
2. yum | apt-get  install --enablerepo=Percona56 Percona-Server-shared-56

mac brew how install ?

Answer (score 1):

Install your packages like this:

```
brew install cmake libffi glib
```

Unfortunately libaio is not available in homebrew, and AIO seems only partly implemented in OSX. You will probably need to adapt the source code for OSX to be able to compile it.

See also this answer: [aio on osx: Is it implemented in the kernel or with user threads? Other Options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902662/aio-on-osx-is-it-implemented-in-the-kernel-or-with-user-threads-other-options)